# Java - compilation error: cannot access Function

Tags: java, maven, osgi, owasp

I have osgi project. Every bundle is a separate maven project. Project is large enough and includes about 10 bundles. Everything works and is ok.

Today I've added one more library - https://code.google.com/p/owasp-java-html-sanitizer/ . I've set all dependencies and ide (netbeans 8) shows everything is ok. However I get the following compilation code in this method:

```
@Override
public void sanitize(Map<String,Object> policies){
    PolicyFactory  policy=(PolicyFactory) policies.get("html0");
    this.code=policy.sanitize(this.code);
}
```

At the second line of the method (this.code...) I get the following compilation error: cannot access Function. Can't understand what it is about...

**EDIT**

Import section:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import org.owasp.html.PolicyFactory;
```

EDIT

```
COMPILATION ERROR : 
-------------------------------------------------------------
com/subjects/SubjectDirItemCore.java:[166,24] error: cannot access Function
1 error
-------------------------------------------------------------
------------------------------------------------------------------------
BUILD FAILURE
------------------------------------------------------------------------
Total time: 1.687s
Finished at: Wed Feb 18 16:11:11 MSK 2015
Final Memory: 14M/205M
```

**EDIT** 
 - I tried via mvn install -X

> org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to
>   execute goal
>   org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:2.3.2:compile
>   (default-compile) on project com.....: Compilation failure
>   ..../subjects/SubjectDirItemCore.java:[166,24] error: cannot access
>   Function
>
> at
>   org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:213)
>     at
>   org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
>     at
>   org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
>     at
>   org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:84)
>     at
>   org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:59)
>     at
>   org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.singleThreadedBuild(LifecycleStarter.java:183)
>     at
>   org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:161)
>     at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:320)   at
>   org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:156)  at
>   org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:537)  at
>   org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:196)   at
>   org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:141)     at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)     at
>   org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:290)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:230)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:409)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:352)
>   Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.CompilationFailureException:
>   Compilation failure /..../subjects/SubjectDirItemCore.java:[166,24]
>   error: cannot access Function
>
> at
>   org.apache.maven.plugin.AbstractCompilerMojo.execute(AbstractCompilerMojo.java:656)
>     at
>   org.apache.maven.plugin.CompilerMojo.execute(CompilerMojo.java:128)
>     at
>   org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:101)
>     at
>   org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:209)
>     ... 19 more [ERROR]

Comment: What JDK you use to compile your code?

Comment: @mkrakhin openjdk version "1.8.0-internal"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0-internal-_2014_11_22_23_46-b00)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.40-b18, mixed mode)

Comment: Ok. If you have guava in your pom.xml what is exact version of it? Also, what version of owasp-java-html-sanitizer you use? It looks like incompatibility issue between old guava and JDK8. Try to compile it against JDK7.

Comment: @mkrakhin I don't have guava at THIS budle pom. Guava 12 is used only for owasp library. However at server side I have java8+gf4.1+ owasp lib bundle and it's ok.

Comment: Try to add latest Guava (18) to your pom.xml. Guava 12 was released before JDK 8, and AFAIK it had some compatibility issues.

Comment: @mkrakhin I've tried with guava 18 - the same error.

Comment: @iJava have you excluded transitive dependency of owasp to guava? If you use latest (r239) of owasp it should resolve to latest guava, but for some older releases they specified exact guava version in their POM.

Comment: In my case, the jar containing the class was not in dependency tree.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the anwser - I used guava 12 instead of guava 11. I took 12 as it was the first version as osgi bundle.

Comment: So as I said the problem was in old version of guava?

Answer (score 2):

In my case this happened when the artifact was posted to the local `Maven` repository without a proper `pom.xml` so the transitive dependencies did not get downloaded. Look for the artifact where the unfound class is located and manually enter it in your pom.xml, that should fix the problem.

Answer (score 0):

This seems jar version issue. Most probably, newer version of jar containing class PolicyFactory  has reduced visibility level of method sanitize. There must be new method which you are supposed to use as earlier method is restricted.

Comment: Check if you can get access to source code of class and see what is definition of PolicyFactory class and its methods. If not, just do ctrl+shift+T and search for PolicyFactory  class. once .class file opens, you can do ctrl+O to check what all methods are exposed by this class and what are public methods.

Comment: I've compiled that library from sources. And PolicyFactory has this method :  public String sanitize(@Nullable String html) {
    return sanitize(html, null, null);
  }

Comment: have you made sure that there are no multiple versions of jar? I can't think of any other reason if method is public.

Comment: Yes, this lib is not osgi bundle, so I created my maven osgi project and build osgi bundle. And this new bundle is added to dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

I had the problem with the Java version: the required dependency had a version too advanced for the project where I had the "cannot access".

But I wouldn't know until I updated the compiler plugin so it would complain correctly about the class file version instead of just "cannot access".